# Equivalency statement wrt Internal Direct Product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that if $G=H_1\times H_2 \times \dots \times H_n$ then the following are equivalent:
$(H_1\times \dots \times H_{i-1})\cap H_i = \{e\} \iff H_i\cap H_j = \{e\}$ I have the $\impliedby$ part down, but I am having a hard time formalizing the reverse.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps your $\;H_i$' s should be $\;G_i$'s ?

Comment: I had it reversed in the first statement, corrected now, thanks!

Comment: Not only that: it should be $$(H_1\times\ldots\times H_{i-1}\times1\ldots\times1)\cap(1\times\ldots\times Hi\times 1\ldots\times 1)$$ isn't it?

Comment: Not in the text I'm using, but that would make sense.

Comment: Well, it's just to be formal as on one side we have a dircet product so we must have the same on the other one.

Comment: Gotcha, that seems like a better way of writing it than Gallian uses.

Comment: Ok, then I think all is wrong: we're talking of the **internal** direct product of subgroups $\;H_1,...,H_n\le G\;$ , and then the condition **must** be that all of them are normal in $\;G\;$ and $$(H_1\cdot\ldots\cdot H_i)\cap H_{i+1}=1$$ Please do note the product is a product of subgroups, which is a subgroup in itself as all those subgroups are *normal*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\;1\neq x\in H_i\cap H_j\;,\;\;i<j\;$ , so

$$1\neq x=1\cdot 1\cdot\ldots\cdot \overbrace{x}^{i}\in (H_1\cdot\ldots\cdot H_i)\cap H_j\;\;\;\leftarrow\text{contradiction}$$

Comment: Thanks, got it.  I appreciate your patience.